# Override With Alternate Windows Credentials

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I want a supervisor override capability for my application.

I want to provide a username login prompt (including domain).  If the user is in the approved list and the password correct, show advanced controls.

What .NET code / functions allow this?

**NOTE:** VB.net answers preferred.  C# also accepted.

**EDIT:** Please note the logged in user is not the user authorizing the override.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check if username and password credentials are correct for a given domain server then you will probably need to use the [LogonUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378184%28VS.85%29.aspx) function. I don't think the function has a managed wrapper so you will have to pinvoke it. See the [PInvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32.logonuser) site for more details and examples.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want to get the list of approved users into the app you can do something like this:

```
Dim adminUser As New List(Of String)(New String() {"admin1", "admin2", "admin3"})
Dim loggedInUser As String = Environment.UserName.ToLower
If Not adminUser.Contains(loggedInUser) Then
    TabControl1.TabPages.RemoveAt(TabControl1.TabPages.IndexOf(Tab_AdminOnly))
End If
```

This assumes you have a Tab (Tab_AdminOnly) that has the items you only want admin people to have. You can disable/remove controls depending on what you need.

Comment: I edited my main post with a clarification.  The logged in user is not the user authorizing the override.

Comment: So is this to be a "back-door" so that an admin can view what the user is doing in the app? Or is this a variation of the application that will require a User to be logged in and then the Admin comes to their desk and, using the User initiated app, is able to log in and do whatever it is the Admin does?